# MySQL include count does not return rows with count zero

Tags: mysql, join, count, row

I have the following MySQL code:

```
SELECT COUNT(e.eid) AS cnt, e.c_id, c.cdesc 
FROM e 
JOIN c on c.c_id = e.c_id 
GROUP by c.c_id
```

Unfortunately the `count` does not take into account rows which are `0`, so for example c_id may have 10 rows but only 9 are displayed (because one of the `e_id`'s count is zero).

I have tried both `LEFT JOIN` and `RIGHT JOIN` with no success. Does anyone have any other suggestions?

Comment: Can you enclose your data for both c and e? Likely one of the table does not have 10 rows

Comment: It's actually null values of e.eid that are being omitted, not 0s. Do you want a count where both e and c records exist for the same c_id, or is it possible for a record to exist on one table but not the other?

Comment: @ajreal no worries, I think I managed to fix it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that what you need is this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt, c.c_id, c.cdesc 
FROM c 
LEFT JOIN e on c.c_id = e.c_id 
GROUP by c.c_id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(e.eid) AS cnt, e.c_id, c.cdesc 
FROM c
left JOIN e on c.c_id = e.c_id 
GROUP by c.c_id
```

Comment: If the e record doesn't exist, e.c_id will be null (as will e.eid) - count(*) and c.c_id in the main select would (probably) be better.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt, e.c_id, c.cdesc 
FROM e 
JOIN c on c.c_id = e.c_id 
GROUP by c.c_id
```